# selecting checkboxes based on value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have the code below. I need to add some html buttons for certain companies to be selected when the link is clicked. Sorta like a select all, select none. But it will be select corporate companies, select franchise companies, etc. All companies are based on ID. How can I use the value in my input type to be checked based on these links?
Example:

Link: Select Corporate. (ID's that should be checked after clicking the link: 1, 14, 17, 47)

```
  <p>
<input type="checkbox" name="sites[]" id="site-1" value="1" checked="checked"/>
<label for="site-1" style="float: none; display: inline; ">Company 1</label>
</p>
<p>
<input type="checkbox" name="sites[]" id="site-14" value="14" checked="checked"/>
<label for="site-14" style="float: none; display: inline; ">Company 14</label>
</p>
<p>
<input type="checkbox" name="sites[]" id="site-17" value="17" checked="checked"/>
<label for="site-17" style="float: none; display: inline; ">Company 17</label>
</p>
<p>
<input type="checkbox" name="sites[]" id="site-47" value="47" checked="checked"/>
<label for="site-47" style="float: none; display: inline; ">Company 47</label>
</p>
```

This is the code I currently have for select all, select none, and what actually generates all my companies that can be checked:

```
<p><label>Show on Sites:<br><a href="" onclick="$('sites').select('input[type=checkbox]').each(function(e){if(!e.checked)e.click();}); return false;">Select All</a> | <a href="" onclick="$('sites').select('input[type=checkbox]').each(function(e){if(e.checked)e.click();}); return false;">Select None</a></label></p>
            <div style="float: left;" id="sites">
                -- Select brand first --
                <?
                if($promotion->id) {
                    $sites = DBObject::getObjects('Company', "company_id IN (SELECT company_id FROM company_promotions WHERE promotion_id = '{$promotion->id}')");
                    foreach($sites AS $site) {
                        ?>
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?= $site->id ?>">
                        <?
                    }
                }
                ?>
            </div>
```

Comment: I might add, There are about 50 companies in my list, these are just 4 from the list. P.S Thank you stackoverflow members for your assistance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function checkCheckboxesByIds(ids) {
     $(':checkbox').removeAttr('checked');   
     $.each(ids, function(i, id) {
        $('#site-' + id).attr('checked', 'checked'); 
     });
}

checkCheckboxesByIds([1, 14, 17, 47]);
```

Comment: $(':checkbox[id$=' + id + ']');

Comment: $(':checkbox[value=' + id + ']'); is another way

Comment: or Simply,`function selectCheckboxesById(ids) {
     $.each(ids, function(i, id) {
         elements.push($('#site-' + id)).attr('checked', 'checked'); 
     });
}`

Comment: @CF What is `elements` and why are you pushing array elements to it? :P

Comment: @thedixon, wouldn't 7 match 17, 27, 37, etc?

Comment: I was simply pointing out the above wouldn't work as the bracket wasn't closed (the post got edited after I made the comment) :)

Comment: @alex, Copy & paste issue. ;)  `function selectCheckboxesById(ids) { 
    $.each(ids, function(i, id) { 
        $('#site-' + id).attr('checked', 'checked'); 
    }); 
}`

Answer (score 1):

working demo here: [http://jsfiddle.net/KBNpQ/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/KBNpQ/2/)

i would group my checkboxes using class names:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="sites[]" id="site-1" value="1" class="corporate"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="sites[]" id="site-2" value="2" class="corporate franchise"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="sites[]" id="site-3" value="3" class="corporate"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="sites[]" id="site-4" value="4" class="corporate"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="sites[]" id="site-5" value="5" class="franchise"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="sites[]" id="site-6" value="6" class="franchise"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="sites[]" id="site-7" value="7" class="franchise corporate"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="sites[]" id="site-8" value="8" class="franchise"/>
```

in this sample 8 companies, 3 franchise, 3 corporate and 2 both.

now in you HTML:

```
<a href="corporate">Corporate</a>
<a href="franchise">Franchise</a>
<a href="#" id="all">All</a>
<a href="#" id="none">None</a
```

>

in your jQuery:

```
$('a').live('click', function(){
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').removeAttr('checked');
    $('input[type="checkbox"].' + href).attr('checked','checked');
    return false;
});

$('a#all').live('click', function(){
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').attr('checked', 'checked');
});

$('a#none').live('click', function(){
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').removeAttr('checked');
});
```

your php part would look like this

```
...

foreach($sites AS $site) {
?>
    <input type="hidden" value="<?= $site->id ?>" class="<?=$site->type ?>">
<?
}

...
```

$site->type should contain the type values like 'franchise' or 'corporate'

Comment: Can you please check my code I posted above in original question? I've added the php script which generates the checkboxes. How would I incorporate your example with it?

Comment: added the php stuff $site->type is my guess, don't know  the name of your object key

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend adding classes to group the companies together. For example:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="corporate" name="sites[]" id="site-1" value="1" checked="checked"/>
<label for="site-1" style="float: none; display: inline; ">Company 1</label>
</p>
<p>
<input type="checkbox" class="franchise" name="sites[]" id="site-14" value="14" checked="checked"/>
<label for="site-14" style="float: none; display: inline; ">Company 14</label>
</p>
<p>
<input type="checkbox" class="franchise" name="sites[]" id="site-17" value="17" checked="checked"/>
<label for="site-17" style="float: none; display: inline; ">Company 17</label>
</p>
<p>
<input type="checkbox" class="corporate" name="sites[]" id="site-47" value="47" checked="checked"/>
<label for="site-47" style="float: none; display: inline; ">Company 47</label>
</p>
```

Then you could query those DOM elements based on class alone and style them, add buttons, etc.

`$(".corporate").attr('checked', 'checked');`

Furthermore you could style up the different entities at any time.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a loop, and this is assuming that you have the companies you want in an array:

```
var corp_company_ids = [1,14,17,47,...];

for( var i = 0; i < company_ids.length; i++) {
  $('input:checkbox[value="' + corp_company_ids[i] + '"]').attr('checked', 'checked');
}
```

A similar method can be used to uncheck/check both corporate and franchise companies.

Answer (score 0):

Your button:

```
<button type="button" data-sites="1,14,17,47">
```

And the JS code:

```
(function($){
  var $inputs = $("input[name='sites[]']");

  $("button[data-sites]").click(function(){
    var sites = $(this).data("sites").split(","),
        sitesLen = sites.length;

    $inputs.filter(":checked").removeAttr('checked');

    while(sitesLen--) {
      $inputs.filter("#site-" + sites[sitesLen]).attr('checked','checked');
    }
  });
})(jQuery)
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than providing a list of ids for each group, I would add a class for each group:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="sites[]" id="site-1" value="1" class="corporate" />
<input type="checkbox" name="sites[]" id="site-12" value="12" class="franchise" />
```

and have a function to select groups by class name:

```
<a href="#" onclick="return SelectGroup('corporate')">Corporate companies</a>
<a href="#" onclick="return SelectGroup('franchise')">Franchise companies</a>


function SelectGroup(groupName) {
    $(':checkbox').removeAttr('checked');
    $(':checkbox.'+groupName).attr('checked', 'checked');
}
```

Comment: Oops, just noticed that @ezmilhouse and @McStretch already suggested the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a small JQuery Function. The benefit here is that a checkbox can be a part of multiple types. It is not said that one checkbox can only serve one purpose ( i.e. franchise ). I think this gives you that little more flexibility..

**HTML**

```
<html>
    <body><p>
        <input type="checkbox" name="sites[]" id="site-1" value="1"/>
        <label for="site-1" style="float: none; display: inline; ">Company 1</label>
        </p>
        <p>
            <input type="checkbox" name="sites[]" id="site-14" value="14"/>
            <label for="site-14" style="float: none; display: inline; ">Company 14</label>
        </p>
        <p>
            <input type="checkbox" name="sites[]" id="site-17" value="17"/>
            <label for="site-17" style="float: none; display: inline; ">Company 17</label>
        </p>
        <p>
            <input type="checkbox" name="sites[]" id="site-47" value="47"/>
            <label for="site-47" style="float: none; display: inline; ">Company 47</label>
        </p>
        <input type="button" id="button" value="Test" />
        <input type="button" id="button2" value="Test2" />
    </body>
</html>
```

**JQuery**

```
function checkFirmButton(arrIDs) {
    // uncheck all boxes first
    $(':checkbox').each(function(index){$(this).attr('checked', false)});

    // check boxes for this company
    var arrCheckboxes = $(':checkbox');
    arrCheckboxes.each(function(index) {
        if (jQuery.inArray($(this).val(), arrIDs) > -1) {
            $(this).attr('checked', true);
        }
    });
}
$("#button").click(function(){
    checkFirmButton(['14', '47']);
});
$("#button2").click(function(){
    checkFirmButton(['1', '17', '47']);
});
```

For a working version, check [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ykv6d/)

Comment: You can use your php script to loop through the records, and fill the arrays appropriately.